# ssh can not establish connection

Tags: networking, ssh, ip

I have several machines connected on the same network:

- A: 134.157.xxx.xxx
- B: 134.157.yyy.yyy
- C: 134.157.zzz.zzz

My problem is that A can not connect anymore to C. But:

- A can ssh to A and B
- B can ssh to A and B and C
- C can ssh to A and B and C

Here are some command outputs from A:

```sh
~$ telnet 134.157.zzz.zzz 22
Trying 134.157.zzz.zzz...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

```sh
~$ ping 134.157.zzz.zzz
PING 134.157.zzz.zzz (134.157.zzz.zzz) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 134.157.zzz.zzz: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.283 ms
64 bytes from 134.157.zzz.zzz: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.315 ms
64 bytes from 134.157.zzz.zzz: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.314 ms
^C
--- 134.157.zzz.zzz ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2082ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.283/0.304/0.315/0.014 ms
```

```sh
~$ ssh -vvv 134.157.zzz.zzz
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "134.157.zzz.zzz" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 134.157.zzz.zzz [134.157.zzz.zzz] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 134.157.zzz.zzz port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 134.157.zzz.zzz port 22: Connection timed out
```

It already worked before, no config file changed, rebooting A does not change anything.

How should I investigate?

**[edit]**

```sh
# on C
~$ tcpdump src 134.157.xxx.xxx -vv -i eno3
~$ tcpdump src 134.157.yyy.yyy -vv -i eno3
# on A
~$ ssh 134.157.zzz.zzz
# on B
~$ ssh 134.157.zzz.zzz
```

Only the command started on B gives an output on C.

**[/edit]**

**[second edit]**

```sh
# on A
~$ tcpdump -vv -i any dst 134.157.zzz.zzz
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
12:32:18.609219 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24010, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    AAA.33648 > 134.157.zzz.zzz.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0xf9fc (correct), seq 3301194634, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2209953097 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:32:19.628185 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24011, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    AAA.33648 > 134.157.zzz.zzz.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0xf601 (correct), seq 3301194634, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2209954116 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:32:21.676188 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24012, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    AAA.33648 > 134.157.zzz.zzz.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0xee01 (correct), seq 3301194634, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2209956164 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
# and so on until timeout
```

**[/second edit]**

**[third edit]**

```sh
# on A
~$ arp -an # contains 134.157.zzz.zzz with correct hardware address
~$ arp -d 134.157.yyy.yyy # success
~$ arp -d 134.157.zzz.zzz # error (see below)
SIOCDARP(dontpub): Network is unreachable
# on C
~$ arp -an # does not contain 134.157.xxx.xxx
~$ arp -s 134.157.xxx.xxx aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa # adds it, but solves nothing
~$
```

**[/third edit]**

**[fourth edit]**

```sh
# After a while running
# tcpdump -vv -i any dst 134.157.zzz.zzz
# on A, I finally got
13:19:09.716711 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 134.157.zzz.zzz tell 134.157.mmm.mmm, length 46
13:23:55.162747 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 134.157.zzz.zzz tell 134.157.nnn.nnn, length 46
13:29:59.119983 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 134.157.zzz.zzz tell 134.157.nnn.nnn, length 46
# which is strange...
```

**[/fourth edit]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem : the netmask was wrong on A (255.255.255.128 instead of 255.255.255.0). We probably missed this when updating the network.

Answer (score 1):

As ICMP is working between A and C, this issue is likely occurring on the higher layers of the stack. As B can reach C it is unlikely to be at the application layer.

My guess is a firewall restriction.

To verify thus I would be using tcpdump or similar to see what packets are received and sent - starting off with tcpdump on C to see if it is receiving packets from A, then working backwards.

Comment: I added the output of tcpdump which shows no packet is received from A.

Comment: OK, what happens if you run tcpdump on a? The additional output provided says the traffic is not arriving on C, so its likely a routing or firewall issue on a, or conceivably a cabling issue. (Also, you are better off using "-i any" for dumps in case an unexpected interface is being used.

Comment: I added the tcpdump from A, which shows packets leaving. Would a cabling issue be compatible with the ouput of ping? The firewall issue is a strange option since no additional rule exist for this specific IP (and other IP's do access C with success).

Comment: Its late, I'm struggling to think, but it cant be a cabling issue as C can reach A.  When you do a tcpdump you try look for traffic both to and from the IP (ie tcpdump src or dst X.X.X.X ...) and run it on both A and C.  Also when you say "the same network", do you mean all directly connected to each other through a switch or something more complicated?  It is conceivable your netmasks are wrong and/or there is an rp_filter kicking in.

Comment: I found ! Look at the (stupid) answer :)